# React Native: Images from uri not being rendered on Android using String interpolation to hand over token

Tags: android, react-native

I am currently working on a React Native App that involves images. I use the following code to display them:

```
//...       
      <View key={uriFromArray}>
              <Image
                style={styles.itemimage}
                source={
                  {
                    uri: uriFromArray,
                    headers: {
                      Authorization: `Bearer ${graphToken}`,
                    },
                  }
                }
              />
            </View>
//...
```

On iOS, this works totally fine, on Android though, the images are not being rendered, neither on a virtual nor a physical device. Weirdly enough, images are being rendered if I copy the acutal token string  to `Authorization` instead of using String interpolation to hand over the token.

Does anybody have an idea of what could be wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try concatenating string before the component renders like:

```
const header = `Bearer ${graphToken}`;
```

Then pass it to Authorization key in the Image uri header prop